# Regular Expressions not Working in jQuery Validation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm having difficulty getting regular expressions to work with jQuery Validation.  Suppose I take a simple regex that requires a minimum of 8 characters to match:

```
(?=.{8,})
```

If plug this into a [JavaScript-based regular expression tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), it works just fine.  8 or more characters match, 7 or less does not.

Further, if I test this in C# it works as well:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?=.{8,})");
        if (regex.IsMatch(myInput))
        {
            // Hits this code when myInput >= 8 characters
        }
```

Next, I use a ValidationAttribute in a view model to emit jQuery Validation to ensure that the user's input matches the expression:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"(?=.{8,})", ErrorMessage="Does not match.")]
    public string MyInput { get; set; }
```

At this point, it breaks down.  No matter what I type in the field does not match.  The HTML emitted is as follows:

```
    <input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Does not match." 
            data-val-regex-pattern="(?=.{8,})"  id="MyInput" name="MyInput"
            type="text" value="" />
```

I've tried different regular expressions, to no avail.  Is there something different about regular expressions in jQuery Validation that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
RegularExpression(@"^.{8,}$")
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Interesting.  This regular expression works on the web page, but fails in the server code.  Basically the reverse of my original problem.  It is as though I need to match the input to two different regular expressions, one in the browser and another to validate back at the server.  Strange.

Comment: Hmm, strange. What about `RegularExpression(@".{8,}")` ?

Comment: I just tested on C# and the regular expression in the answer works. Aren't you making a mistake somewhere else?

Comment: You're right, I made an error when testing this.  This should work, although I'm not entirely clear on why the original expression works everywhere except in the jQuery Validation.  My understanding was that the ?= construct says to look ahead, while the .{8,} checks for 8 to any number of characters.  Maybe the jQuery/JavaScript implementation of regular expressions  is inconsistent with .NET.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome. Yep, there are some variations on the implementations. Could you please mark the answer as accepted?